# <a href='tel:' not working

Tags: android, html, ibm-mobilefirst, tel

i am trying to dial a phone call on link, for that i used "tel" tag, its giving error that protocol not supported, i used following in HTML.

```
<a href='tel:9761111769'>+91 9761111769</a> not working.
```

i have used required meta tag

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

also have added following permissions in manifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

and following code in config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="true"/>
```

i trying to changes in syntax and implementing some solutions from web but its not working.... please tell me what thing i have to check in my code or any changes in existing code..Thanks

Comment: i not using java here only html and jquery and javascript.

Comment: we are using the same thing in our app but we have and Android Feature <feature name="PhoneDialer">
           <param name="android-package" value="ca.company.AppName.PhoneDialer"/>
     </feature>. Inside the Android Project we have a PhoneDialer.java which contains a function to call the "tel" protocol with number specified. However I can't answer your question which seems this feature is disabled

Comment: we also have another App in android and same thing are working fine there... but now we want it in worklight environment...

Comment: Yes we are using Worklight too to develop our application. As I mentioned, we have added A feature in config.xml as in my pervious comment and Inside Android nativeResources folder > src > ca > company > AppName, we created a Java file called "PhoneDialer.java" which has a definition of how the "tel" protocol will use the Phone number provided and access the Phone dialer.

Comment: The code above is showing single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: @BillyNair yes because i am using html string                                              "<a href='tel:9761111769'>+919761111769</a>"     like this

Comment: HTML uses double quotes for strings. If you are using PHP you will want to do something like this ```$link = '<a href="tel:9761111769">+919761111769</a>';``` where the HTML double quotes will be printed to the browser